# NGINX prevent direct access to directory but allow rewrites

Tags: nginx

Using NGINX to proxy to a cluster of RIAK nodes*. I have a rewrite rule like

```
rewrite ^/bucket-([a-z]+)/object-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.+)$ /riak/$1/$2 break;
```

and a location block

```
location /riak/ {
  proxy_pass      http://riak_servers/riak/;
}
```

Which will redirect to one of the RIAK servers. Problem is, users can directly access http://server/riak/ and get directly to the RIAK cluster and bucket information. I want to only allow access to users requesting resources via the rewritten URL. I'd rather avoid any `if`s or multiple `location` blocks to catch everything. I'm probably missing something obvious.

NGINX 1.0.11

<sub>*This is generally a bad idea since anyone with access to the NGINX server can `put`/`post` stuff into your RIAK cluster. You should prevent all request types except `GET` and `HEAD`, also it's probably a good idea to remove andy `X-*` headers put in by RIAK. I don't think exposing the VClock value is a security issue but best to be safe.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [internal directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) to mark it as an internal location which is not directly accessible.